# How to remove the title from toolbar menu in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, menu, toolbar

i have this toolbar

[image]

i want to remove the title of the fragment so i can display more items

is it from the xml file or the activity?

because i tried to add this to my main activity:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar).setTitle("");

toolbar.setTitle(null)
```

but none of them worked

any suggestion?

this is MainActiviy code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {











override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    









    val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)



    setupBottomNavMenu(navController)
    setupSideNavigationMenu(navController)
    setupActionBar(navController)
```

Comment: Are you using a Navigation component?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes

Comment: Post your relevant code of your setup

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own tool bar for each fragment and customize it as per your requirement. I have made a common toolbar xml file and reusing it in every fragment and customizing it. Look :

common_toolbar.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/const_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/back_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_normal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_five"
        android:text="Back"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_fifteen"
        app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_action_chevron_left"
        app:drawableTint="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/menu"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_fifteen"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

And then adding it to fragments's UI. Let's say, adding to fragment_user_details.xml

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar_common"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_user_details"/>
<!-- 
 Other View widgets
 -->
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As each fragment has its own tool bar, so I am getting it by it's id and customize as per my requirement. Make sure Activity has **Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar** theme.

Menu Items can also be added like below:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
return true;
}
```

Comment: Previous code did not work because you are using Navigation Component. I am achieving this result by using just updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a Navigation component you can use the **`addOnDestinationChangedListener`** to set your custom title after your setup method.

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
   if(destination.id == R.id.xxxx) {
       //If in your setup you are using a Toolbar
       toolbar.title = ""
       //supportActionBar?.title = "" //If you are using setSupportActionBar()
   } else {
       //
   }
}
```

Comment: i tired to add this, it didn't work as well